# Capture input="file" value after clicking history.back()

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to capture the selected file `<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />` 
on the previous page after I click back button?

`<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back();" />`

for text, textarea, dropdown I don't encounter any problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to capture the selected file on previous page after you click the history.back() function.

Try to refresh the page, not a full refresh. I tried and i captured the name.

Answer (score 0):

Some Browsers by-default save the filename in File Input Control when we navigate Back by using Browser's Back Button. If you want to have Perfect Control over perviously selected file then I will suggest you to Load Next Page's Content Dynamically and make user feel that new page has been loaded. You can *history.pushState* to manipulate Browser's History and URL Bar etc.